# prepend command with env variable - including sub command

Tags: php, bash, laravel, docker

I need to add an environment variable to the `php artisan migrate` commands of Laravel for use with docker, like:

```
env DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 php artisan migrate
```

I created a function in my `.zshrc` file like this:

```
function migrate() {
  (env DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 php artisan migrate $*)
}
```

however the way Laravel's command structure works is like this:

```
 migrate
  migrate:install      Create the migration repository
  migrate:refresh      Reset and re-run all migrations
  migrate:reset        Rollback all database migrations
  migrate:rollback     Rollback the last database migration
  migrate:status       Show the status of each migration
```

so this doesn't work for a command like this:

```
migrate:refresh --seed
```

is there a way I can write the function to also add the variable for all these 'child' commands too?

Comment: can't you have several env variables? it may be simpler.

Comment: if i understand you correctly, my .env file needs to have `DB_HOST=mysql` but on CLI (which is outside the docker container) needs `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` which is why i'm exploring this solution

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to be able to do this: `migrate refresh --seed`, then

```
migrate() {
  local subcommand=$1
  shift
  env DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 php artisan migrate:"$subcommand" "${@}")
}
```

---

Hmmm, perhaps

```
artisan() {
  env DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 php artisan "${@}")
}
for subcommand in    \
    migrate          \
    migrate:install  \
    migrate:refresh  \
    migrate:reset    \
    migrate:rollback \
    migrate:status
do
    alias $subcommand="artisan $subcommand"
done
```

That would get you some tab completion for free as well.

Comment: @daviestar, I voted to reject your edit. Feel free to add your own answer and accept it if only part of my answer suits you.

Answer (score 0):

```
artisan() {
  env DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 \

  php artisan "${@}"
}
```

The generic function for Laravel+Docker users to have the flexibility to update environment variables for use with `artisan` outside docker containers.

Thanks to @glenn-jackman for pointing me in the right direction!